# pam_cracklib minlen not working as expected

Tags: linux, debian, cracklib

im trying to enforce a password policy using pam_cracklib on Debian with this configuration

> minlen=10 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1

but i still can create passwords with less than 10 length.

**Edit**

this is the content of my /etc/pam.d/common-password

````
password requisite    pam_cracklib.so   retry=3 minlen=10 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 maxrepeat=3 difork=7 reject_username enforce_for_root

password [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512```
````

Comment: How did you configure this? Post your config files

Comment: i edited my question with my config file content